# playstore in app purchase application s

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

i have downloaded in app purcahse app from playstore but i have not entered any bank a/c so will i get any bill from playstore.it was written that it is in app purchase but it was in Top Free list. please help me

Answer (score 0):

In-app purchase means just that. You can purchase, for real money, additional features or upgrades to the app. The app is free, but a lot of games almost require spending money after beginning gameplay in order to proceed or finish. You do not need to enter credit card information to download or use an app with in-app purchasing and you will not be charged without purposefully selecting and confirming an in-app purchase.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have not entered any credit card no. so will they send any bill on my home address?

Comment: No. Who gets paper bills these days, anyhow?

Comment: And be sure to mark an answer as your approved solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanx it was so much helpful.....

Answer (score 0):

It is just an indicator to indicate that selected app has few purchases that can be purchased after you download the app and open it.

You can purchase any item you want after you open the app.

Image shows the in-app purchase indicator below open button.

[image]